# Concat grouped records

Tags: mysql

I have two related Tables, "projects" and "projects_formats" by projectID.

I need a Query that could supply me with projects and for each row I want to concat the set of Formats desired for such project.

Now, my query is:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
       f.*,
       CONCAT(f.formatID, ', ') as formats
FROM projects as p INNER JOIN project_formats as f ON f.projectID=p.ID 
WHERE p.ended=0
GROUP BY f.projectID
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `CONCAT`, try [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
       f.*,
       GROUP_CONCAT(f.formatID SEPARATOR ', ') as formats
FROM projects as p INNER JOIN project_formats as f ON f.projectID=p.ID 
WHERE p.ended=0
GROUP BY f.projectID
```